# SAS retain statement

Tags: if-statement, sas, retain

Suppose I have a dataset with three variables:

ID    Year    Status 

1    2017     Y

1     2017     N

1      2018     N

1     2018     Y

2      2017     Y

2      2017        

2      2018     N

2     2018     N

I would like to create a fourth column called NEW which has three possible values ('Yonly' 'Nonly' and 'yesno'). In the example above the output will be:

ID      Year      Status   NEW

1      2017       Y          

1       2017      N         yesno

1        2018      N       

1       2018      Y         yesno 

2       2017      Y      

2        2017                  yesonly

2       2018      N      

2       2018      N       noonly

Note: could have missing data. My solution so far is wrong:

```
retain tmp '';
by ID Year;
if Status='Y' then tmp='Yonly';
if Status='N' then tmp='Nonly';
if tmp='Yonly' and Status='N' then tmp='yesno';
  if tmp='Nonly' and Status='Y' then tmp='yesno';
if last.Year=1 then NEW=tmp;
```

Please help? Any method will do, you don't have to use RETAIN.

Comment: @Joe the grouping is by ID and year. Alright, I shall modify the examples to make this clearer. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to define the length of TMP.  Your current code will set the length of TMP to 1 since the first usage is the initial value listed in the RETAIN statement.

You are missing an initialization step for when starting a new group.

```
if first.year then tmp=' ';
```

Your method can only set the result on the last record for each group. If you want all observations in a group to have the same value then I would suggest using a double DOW loop.  The first loop can be used to see if there are any 'Y' or 'N' status. Then you can calculate your NEW variable. Then a second loop will read in the data for the group again and write the values out.  Because all observations for a group are processed in a single data step iteration there is no need to use RETAIN.

```
data want ;
  do until (last.year) ;
    set have ;
    by id year ;
    y = y or (status='Y');
    n = n or (status='N');
  end;
  length new $8;
  if Y and N then new='yesno';
  else if Y then new='yesonly';
  else if N then new='noonly';
  else new='none';
  drop y n ;
  do until (last.year) ;
    set have ;
    by id year ;
    output ;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's along the lines of what you were doing, but it's better to do the conditionals more like this.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id year;
  retain last_status;
  if first.year then last_status = status;
  if last.year then do;
    if status = last_status or missing(last_status) then new=cats(status,'only');
    else if missing(status) then new=cats(last_status,'only');
    else new='yesno';
  end;
run;
```

`retain` the value from the first row, and then on the last row just consider what to do based on the two variables - it's fairly straightforward that way.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, not 100% correct solution though. If there are more than 2 rows of  Year per ID, and it goes Y to N to Y from one year to another then I think your solution breaks down.

Comment: If that's a possibility then you should include that in the example data.